# Issue with state in react-native app using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch additional data `onEndReached` inside a react native `Flatlist` component.

It works well except that I can't manage to add elements to my state, instead the only thing that works right now is fetching all the data as well as the additional data needed.

This currently works but isn't what I want to do.

```
case FETCH_NEARBY:
  return { ...state, nearby: action.payload.data.nearby };
```

Instead, I'd like to make the following logic work:

```
case FETCH_NEARBY:
  return { ...state, nearby: [ ...state.nearby, ...action.payload.data.nearby ] };
```

But the above code doesn't work, it just doesn't return the state for nearby anymore.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an interim value. What you are attempting is trying to append state to state.

```
const updateNearby = (prev, newValue) => {
  return [ ...prev, newValue ]
}

case FETCH_NEARBY:
  const interimValue = updateNearby(
    state.nearby, 
    ...action.payload.data.nearby 
  )

  return { ...state, nearby: interimValue }
```

Comment: Thank you but this has the same result as before.

Comment: @Hugo I've updated the answer to show the call to a function outside the context of the case statement.

Comment: Meta-note: Code is formatted with at least four spaces on each line (8 when in list formatting), not using three backticks before and after the code. You can also highlight the text and press CTRL+K, or click the symbol that looks like `{}` in the top bar (with the code highlighted)

Comment: Thanks for the information @Zoe and I'll be sure to amend the way I add code examples in the future.

Comment: Sorry tried that as well but this time it no longer returns the state.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it without making a copy of the payload?

```
case FETCH_NEARBY:
  return { 
    ...state, 
    nearby: [ ...state.nearby, action.payload.data.nearby ] 
  };
```

this code will def work as long as `action.payload.data.nearby` isnt undefined. Hope that helps :)